# When Improve Edit the side bar content is displaying in the bottom of the page

Tags: bug, design, suggested-edits, sidebar

When review the suggested edit - click the **edit** link from the post and **Improve Edit** in the screen the side bar of **How to Edit** and **How to Format** sections are displaying in the bottom of the page.

GIF for the same:

**Meta Stack Exchange:**

> [image: side bar MSE]

**Stack Overflow:**

[image: side bar SO]

Comment: What did you use to create the .gifs? They're nice! :D

Comment: @Blue Tool name is LiceCap